# Show all div if none of link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page name url.com/yourfirstpage/ when i go to the page all the div are hidden by default (display:none) 
if we target #sec1 as url.com/yourfirstpage/#sec1 it only displays sec1 and hide others.
I was wondering if we go the url without having anchor id like url.com/yourfirstpage/ it needs to show all the divs.

```css
#sec1, #sec2, #sec3{
 display:none;
}
#sec1:target{
 display:block;
}
#sec2:target{
 display:block;
}
#sec3:target{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sec1">sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2">sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3">sec3</a>

<div id="sec1" class="page"> this is sec1</div>
<div id="sec2" class="page"> this is sec2</div>
<div id="sec3" class="page"> this is sec3</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show all the content? You question is a little hard for me to get straight so that's why I'm looking for some explanation :)

Comment: You cannot use the `target` mechanism for this, because you cannot target multiple elements. You will need some JS.

Comment: if there is no anchor id attached to the url, it needs to show all div by default

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54644619/860099) is duplicate of this question, but with interesting answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick in case you are able to modify your HTML structure. The idea is to have the elements visible and then we hide them using `:target`. Since we don't have previous sibling selector or parent selector, I used id within a parent element to be able to select any element:

```css
#sec1:target .page:nth-child(n+2){
  display: none;
}

#sec2:target .page:nth-child(2n+1){
  display: none;
}

#sec3:target .page:nth-last-child(n+2){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sec1">sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2">sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3">sec3</a>

<div id="sec1">
  <div id="sec2">
    <div id="sec3">
      <div class="page"> this is sec1</div>
      <div class="page"> this is sec2</div>
      <div class="page"> this is sec3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It can work with any number of sections and we can improve the CSS code as follow:

```css
#sec1:target .page:not(:nth-child(1)),
#sec2:target .page:not(:nth-child(2)),
#sec3:target .page:not(:nth-child(3)),
#sec4:target .page:not(:nth-child(4)),
#sec5:target .page:not(:nth-child(5)) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sec1">sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2">sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3">sec3</a>
<a href="#sec4">sec4</a>
<a href="#sec5">sec5</a>

<div id="sec1">
  <div id="sec2">
    <div id="sec3">
      <div id="sec4">
        <div id="sec5">
          <div class="page"> this is sec1</div>
          <div class="page"> this is sec2</div>
          <div class="page"> this is sec3</div>
          <div class="page"> this is sec4</div>
          <div class="page"> this is sec5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski almost the same ;) based on  the same idea as mine but instead of nested element, we have sibling elements

Answer (score 2):

this quick approach may help

you can do with `!` selector in CSS by using postcss plugins

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', () => {
        a.parentElement.classList.add('targeted')
    })
})
```

```css
.targeted div {
  display: none;
}
.targeted div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#sec1">sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2">sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3">sec3</a>

<div id="sec1" class="page"> this is sec1</div>
<div id="sec2" class="page"> this is sec2</div>
<div id="sec3" class="page"> this is sec3</div>
```