# Show section/div depends on after hash # value in link

Tags: html, css

I have following page

```css
section {
 height: 1000px;
 background: yellow;
 margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="one">Section one</section>
<section id="two">Section two</section>
```

It is possible using html/css only to show only ONE section if user came from link which contains section id after hash e.g

- if user go to link http://my-site/page#one he should only see section one
- if user go to link http://my-site/page#two he should only see section two
- if user go to link http://my-site/page he should see all sections

?

Comment: I think you must use js/jquery

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101652/8620333 ? it works with any number of sections

Comment: @TemaniAfif And nests infinitely… That solution is not better than anything we've come up with here. Like the solutions here, your CSS must be modified as the DOM changes.

Comment: @AndyHoffman actually it's the only solution I see that works with many sections without duplicating the content ;) [by the way, I never said it's better, it's a possible duplicate since the question is almost the same to not say exactly the same]

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes the question is allmost duplicate, however it motivate people to bring new creative solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution contains no HTML nesting and scales easily. It uses `:target` and [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to find matches and show only the targeted `section`.

```css
 /* Display all sections initially */
section {
 height: 1000px;
 background: yellow;
 margin: 50px;
}

/* Hide all targeted sections initially */
span:target ~ section {
  display: none;
}
 
/* Display only the targeted section */
span:nth-of-type(1):target ~ section:nth-of-type(1),
span:nth-of-type(2):target ~ section:nth-of-type(2),
span:nth-of-type(3):target ~ section:nth-of-type(3),
span:nth-of-type(4):target ~ section:nth-of-type(4),
span:nth-of-type(5):target ~ section:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a>
<a href="#two">two</a>
<a href="#three">three</a>
<a href="#four">four</a>
<a href="#five">five</a>
<!-- <a href="#n">n</a> -->

<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
<span id="three"></span>
<span id="four"></span>
<span id="five"></span>
<!-- <span id="n"></span> -->

<section>Section one</section>
<section>Section two</section>
<section>Section three</section>
<section>Section four</section>
<section>Section five</section>
<!-- <section>Section n</section> -->
```

Comment: this approach will work with 3,4,... and more sections? If yes - how?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Please take another look. This new approach scales and avoids nesting-related performance issues.

Comment: I test your solution on chrome, firefox and safari - works nice - thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 6):

You can investigate the use of the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class, but you might struggle to show all of the sections when the URL hash is empty.

For example:

```css
section:not(:target) { display:none; }
section:target { display: block }
```

```html
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>

<section id="one">Section one</section>
<section id="two">Section two</section>
```

Comment: That's as far as I made it, too. But this doesn't satisfy the last requirement. When nothing is targeted, but sections should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Probably JavaScript is the best way to go about this, but if you **really** don't want to use it, you can use the `:target` approach suggested by BenM in combination with duplicated HTML.

When there is no `:target`, you show the duplicated HTML. When there is a target, you show the target and hide everything else.

Like this:

```css
#one,
#two {
  display: none;
}
#one:target,
#two:target {
  display: block;
}
#one:target ~ div,
#two:target ~ div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a>
<a href="#two">two</a>

<div id="one">Section one</div>
<div id="two">Section two</div>
<div id="one-duplicate">Section one</div>
<div id="two-duplicate">Section two</div>
```

Comment: this approach will work with 3,4,... and more sections? If yes - how?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski if you just add additional sections – e.g., `#three` and `#three-duplicate`, `#four` and `#four-duplicate` – along with the relevant CSS in the same pattern as above, I see no reason why this couldn't work for infinitely many sections. You could probably slim down the CSS to use classes if you are going to have several sections. The only real structural requirement is that your links must come before your target divs either as siblings or siblings of the target divs' parent container in order to leverage the `~` selector.